# ggplot2: annotation with text, sub/superscript, and calculated values

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I have searched here for a while and my question was partially answered by previous questions/answers. I am learning R, coming from Matlab. As the title says, I have a question about plot annotations. In Matlab it was fairly straightforward to have plot annotations that contained all sorts of data formats, and I am looking for something similar in R. I have already discovered `paste` and managed to put text and numbers into one annotation and I also figured out (to a degree...) what `parse` does, for example when displaying an r squared. My question is, how do I combine the two annotations in the code snippet into one annotation without R yelling at me? My solution with two annotations works for what I need, but I simply would like to know how to do it...

```
a <- 30 # some coefficients
b <- 70
r2 <- 0.87
anno1 <- paste("y = ",b,"ln(x) + ",a) # first annotation with a random equation
anno2 <- paste("r^2 == ", r2) # second annotation with a random r squared

Pdata <- data.frame("X" = 1:10, "Y" = 1:10) # some data

ggplot(Pdata,aes(x=Pdata$X,y=Pdata$Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x=2, y=8, label=anno1, parse=FALSE) +
  annotate("text", x=2, y=7, label=anno2, parse=TRUE)
```

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 6):

It took a while for me to figure this out (for my own projects), but here's a solution:

```
anno3 <- paste("'y ='~",b,"~'ln(x) +'~",a,"~r^2==~", r2)
```

Add it to your plot using `+ annotate("text", x=2, y=6, label=anno3, parse=TRUE)`

The single quote identifies text to not evaluate. Combined, the pasted result should be written like an expression.

Comment: Now how do we do this and have the r^2 on a new line?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do the requested operation by using `bquote`

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = 1:4, y = 1:4)) +
  annotate("text", x=2, y=3,
            label = deparse(bquote(~y ==~  .(b) ~ln(x)~ + .(a)  ~r^2 ==~  .(r2))),
            parse = T)
```

bquote quotes its argument except the terms wrapped in .()  which are evaluated
annotate does not support expressions, one trick to get it to work is to deparse it and then parse it again

[image]

Comment: Running this code works, but it throws an error at me when I try to run it with my actual code. The error is
"Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): label"

Comment: Looking at the code some more, what is the difference between putting the aesthetics into ggplot() as opposed to geom_points()?

Comment: @Rincewind when the aesthetics are provided in the ggplot call they are passed to all subsequent geoms, when there is only one geom this is equivalent to putting data in the geom aes. However, for more complex visualizations I usually have several different data calls in different geoms, or some geoms simply do not support some aesthetics so I avoid putting the `aes` in ggplot call. This is just a preference, one can stop the passing of aes from ggplot by setting `inherit.aes = F` in any geom call. As far the error, I can not replicate it, could you provide an example so I could check it out?

Comment: i figured it out! It wasn't a problem with the annotation code, but rather with the "a" and "b" coefficients, that I gave it. In my actual code I extracted coefficients from a regression and didn't do it properly (they showed als up as "Named num" in the environment instead as just numerical). Thanks!